React Native Image sizing not functioning as intended
I am trying to display an image and have it take up full width and auto height (based on the height of the image). The desired output is this

This is my code


import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import icons from "../constants/icons";

const Post = ({ username, imageRef }) => {
  return (
    <View className="w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-4">
      <View className="flex flex-row items-center justify-start gap-2">
        <Image source={icons.user} resizeMode="contain" className="w-7 h-7" />
        <Text className="text-white font-mmedium text-md">{username}</Text>
      </View>
    <Image
    source={{uri: imageRef}}
    resizeMode="cover"
    className="w-full h-auto"
    />
    </View>
  );
};

const FeedList = ({ posts }) => {
  if (!posts || posts.length === 0) {
    return (
      <View className="w-full flex items-center justify-center">
        <Text className="text-white font-mregular text-md mt-2">
          Follow some people to see their posts
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      scrollEnabled={false}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      data={posts}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.$Fid}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Post username={item.username} imageRef={item.imageRef} />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default FeedList;



I am having issues with the sizing of the image. If I hardcode some values like 'h-10 w-10' then I can see a tiny image aligned to the left of the screen.

EDIT
I found a workaround
This is how I solved the problem


const Post = ({ username, imageRef }) => {
  const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    Image.getSize(imageRef, (width, height) => {
      const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
      const scaleFactor = width / screenWidth;
      const imageHeight = height / scaleFactor;
      setImageHeight(imageHeight);
    });
  }, [imageRef]);

  return (
    <View className="flex items-center justify-center mt-4">
      <View className="w-full flex-row items-center justify-start gap-2">
        <Image source={icons.user} resizeMode="contain" className="w-7 h-7" />
        <Text className="text-white font-mmedium text-md">{username}</Text>
      </View>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: imageRef }}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={{width: '100%', height: imageHeight}}
        className="mt-2"
      />
    </View>
  );
};




This question is similar to: How to force an image to be full width and maintain aspect ratio using React Native?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
